# How do you show the first element of a nodeList on page loading?

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, nodelist

I am cycling through elements within this array using the 'next' and 'previous' buttons.
However I want to show the first element of the array, index [0] when the page is loaded, Rather than having to click 'next' to see the first one.

Would it be best to toggle the css class in some way? Or is there a simpler solution that can be done within the JS code?

```
<body>
<div id='entry1' class='entry'>
Entry1
</div>

<div class ='entry'>
Entry2
</div>

<div class ='entry'>
Entry3
</div>

<div class ='entry'>
Entry4
</div>

<p id="filler"></p>
<button id="back">PREVIOUS</button>
<button id="forward">NEXT</button>
</body>

<script>
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".entry"); 
var i=-1;
var text = "";

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function 
previous() {
if (i > 0) {
text = divs[--i].textContent;
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});

document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function 
next(){
if (i < divs.length - 1) {
text = divs[++i].textContent;
}
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = text;
});
</script>
```

Here is my JS Fiddle:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdmitchell/7pno1ock/#&togetherjs=HwaqreAnQ5)

Comment: Simply use the onload event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: What would be the best way of loading the first element in to this using onload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply initialize the `p` with the text content of the first div. Also you now need to start from index `0`.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
var i=0;
// set the initial content to be the one from the first div
var text = divs[0].textContent;
var filler = document.getElementById("filler");
filler.innerHTML = text;

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function previous() {
  if (i > 0) {
    text = divs[--i].textContent;
  }

  filler.innerHTML = text;
});

document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function next(){
  if (i < divs.length - 1) {
    text = divs[++i].textContent;
  }

  filler.innerHTML = text;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tsvetan, unfortunately this now stalls on the first element.
You must click next twice for the next element to appear...